# When sending beacon frame with scapy my wireshark receive two

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, beacon

I want to send a beacon frame with scapy, that works. But my wireshark receive two instead of one beacon frame, why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

Beacon_SSID = 'fake_beacon'     
broadcast = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
bssid = "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"

beaconframe = RadioTap() / Dot11(addr1 = broadcast, addr2 = bssid, addr3 = bssid) / Dot11Beacon(cap = 0x1104) / Dot11Elt( ID=0, info = Beacon_SSID) / Dot11Elt (ID=1, info = "\x84\x84\x8b\x96\x24\30\x48\x6c") / Dot11Elt (ID=3, info = "\x0b") / Dot11Elt (ID=5, info = "\x00\x01\x00\x00")
        sendp(beaconframe, iface = "wlan0mon")
```

Here is what it looks like in wireshark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOIxW.jpg

(And second, but thats not my main question, how can i number my fake beacon? So beacon frame #1 is called fake_beacon_1, #2 is fake_beacon_2 and so on)